# How to make an infinite async loop on Plasma 5 plasmoids

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, qml, plasmoid, kde-plasma

I'm starting on KDE Plasma 5 plasmoids developments and I'm trying to make a plasmoid that fetches data from an API every 10 seconds and shows it in a Label (from `org.kde.plasma.components`).

In browser environments we can use `setTimeout` with no problems, but what to do in environments like that when these functions aren't available?

I tried to make a `while(true)` loop on `Component.onCompleted` hook, but as expected, the Plasmoid didn't loaded and my CPU went crazy.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.components 2.0 as PlasmaComponents
import org.kde.plasma.extras 2.0 as PlasmaExtras

Row {
    id: 'container'

    Component.onCompleted: {
        let counter = 0;

        while(true) {
            textContainer.text = counter;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    PlasmaComponents.Label {
        id: 'textContainer'
        text: ''
        width: 384
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually much simpler than i thought, just used the [Timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html).

```
Timer {
    interval: 10000
    repeat: true
    running: true
    onTriggered: {
        // The code here
    }
}
```